# correspondence between finite dimensional complex representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I would like to understand the following fact, shall need help, Thank you.

" There is a one- to- one correspondence between the finite dimensional complex representation $\Pi$ of $SU(3)$ and finite dimensional complex linear representation $\pi$ of $sl(3,\mathbb{C})$ and the correspondence is determined by the property that $$\Pi(e^X)=e^{\pi(X)}$$ for all $X\in su(3)\subseteq sl(3,\mathbb{C})$

Comment: The phrase is "one-to-one correspondence."

Comment: And the phrase requires plurals: "representations" (twice) since a ono-to-one correspondence between singlton sets is not very exciting.

Comment: Or maybe, on second reading, the singular is intended, but that makes the intention rather murky: I think it says that for a given finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ there is a correspondence between the sets of Lie group morphisms $SU(3)\to GL(V)$ and of Lie algebra morphisms $sl(3,\Bbb C)\to gl(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

Any complex representation $\Pi:\textrm{SU}(3) \to \textrm{GL}(V)$ determines a unique complex representation $\pi:\mathfrak{sl}_3 \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ such that $$\Pi(e^{X}) = e^{\pi(X)}$$
for all $X$ in the Lie algebra. That any complex representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ on $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ determines a unique Lie group representation of $\textrm{SU}(3)$ on $\textrm{GL}(V)$ with the property above comes from the fact that $\pi_1(\textrm{SU}(3))=0$.